# Run Julia function every time Julia environment launches

Tags: julia

I am moving from R, and I use the [head() function](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/utils/head) a lot. I couldn't find a similar method in Julia, so I wrote one for Julia Arrays. There are couple other R functions that I'm porting to Julia as well.

I need these methods to be available for use in every Julia instance that launches, whether through IJulia or through command line. Is there a "startup script" of sorts for Julia? How can I achieve this?

PS: In case someone else is interested, this is what I wrote. A lot needs to be done for general-purpose use, but it does what I need it to for now.

```
function head(obj::Array; nrows=5, ncols=size(obj)[2])
     if (size(obj)[1] < nrows)
       println("WARNING: nrows is greater than actual number of rows in the obj Array.")
       nrows = size(obj)[1]
     end
     obj[[1:nrows], [1:ncols]]
   end
```

Comment: Just a tangential comment. There is a `head` function for DataFrames in the DataFrames.jl package.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make a `~/.juliarc.jl` file, see the [Getting Started](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/getting-started/?highlight=juliarc) section of the manual.

As for you `head` function, here is how I'd do it:

```
function head(obj::Array; nrows=5, ncols=size(obj,2))
    if size(obj,1) < nrows
        warn("nrows is greater than actual number of rows in the obj Array.")
        nrows = size(obj,1)
    end
    obj[1:nrows, 1:ncols]
end
```