# How to alias quit() to quit?

Tags: julia

This is just a convenience but I think useful. Note that IPython allows a pure quit as does Matlab. Thus it would be reasonble in Julia to allow aliasing.

Thanks for any ideas as to how to do this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Quitting in Julia

If you are using Julia from the command line then **ctrl-d** works. But if your intention is to quit by typing a command this is not possible exactly the way you want it because typing *[quit](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/client.jl#L38)* in the REPL already has a meaning which is return the value associated with quit, which is the function quit.

```
julia> quit
quit (generic function with 1 method)

julia> typeof(quit)
Function
```

#### Also Python

But that's not rare, for example [Python has similar behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730409/exiting-from-python-command-line).

```
>>> quit
Use quit() or Ctrl-D (i.e. EOF) to exit
```

#### Using a macro

Using \q might be nice in the Julia REPL like [in postgres REPL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9463318/how-to-exit-from-postgresql-command-line-utility-psql), but unfortunately \ also [already has a meaning](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/linalg/).  However, if you were seeking a simple way to do this, how about a macro

```
julia> macro q() quit() end

julia> @q
```

> ***Causes Julia to Quit***

If you place the macro definition in a [.juliarc.jl file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25336490/run-julia-function-every-time-julia-environment-launches), it will be available every time you run the interpreter.

Comment: I use the `@q` macro definiton in my startup file, its not as pleasant as `\q` in `psql`, simply because it requires a shit and pinky reach.  OTOH, it fits into the macro world of julia and perhaps I'll remap my caps lock to @.

Answer (score 3):

As waTeim notes, when you type `quit` into the REPL, it simply shows the function itself… and there's no way to change this behavior.  You cannot execute a function without calling it, and there are a limited number of ways to call functions in Julia's syntax.

What you *can* do, however, is change how the Functions are displayed.  This is extremely hacky and is not guaranteed to work, but if you want this behavior badly enough, here's what you can do: hack this behavior into the display method.

```
julia> function Base.writemime(io::IO, ::MIME"text/plain", f::Function)
           f == quit && quit()
           if isgeneric(f)
               n = length(f.env)
               m = n==1 ? "method" : "methods"
               print(io, "$(f.env.name) (generic function with $n $m)")
           else
               show(io, f)
           end
       end
Warning: Method definition writemime(IO,MIME{symbol("text/plain")},Function) in module Base at replutil.jl:5 overwritten in module Main at none:2.
writemime (generic function with 34 methods)

julia> print # other functions still display normally
print (generic function with 22 methods)

julia> quit # but when quit is displayed, it actually quits!

$
```

Unfortunately there's no type more specific than `::Function`, so you must completely overwrite the `writemime(::IO,::MIME"text/plain",::Function)` definition, copying its implementation.

Also note that this is pretty unexpected and somewhat dangerous. Some library may actually end up trying to display the function `quit`… causing you to lose your work from that session.

Answer (score 0):

## Related to Quitting in Julia

I was searching for something simple. This question hasn't been updated since 2017, as I try to learn `Julia` now, and spend some time googling for something simple and similar to python. Here, what I found:
You can use:

```
exit()
```

### Note

I use `julia 1.53`